# The Kubernetes ingress doesn't allow Websocket communication over HTTPS

Tags: websocket, https, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to host my WebAPI service in kubernetes over HTTPS. The service has inbound communications over port 80 and outbound websocket communication over port 81. I have configured AKS Ingress controller with a static IP assigned to it.

The application is working just fine in HTTP protocol but when I enabled TLS certificate to enable HTTPS, the websocket communication is not working any more.

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: mywebapiservice
  namespace: mywebapi
 annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: mywebapi_customclass
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '7200'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '7200'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '7200'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mywebapi.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
      secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: mywebapi.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: >-
              /app/api/ServiceA/subscription
            backend:
              serviceName: ServiceA
              servicePort: 81
          - path: >-
              /app/api/ServiceA/(.+)
            backend:
              serviceName: ServiceA
              servicePort: 80
          - path: >-
              /app/api/ServiceB/subscription
            backend:
              serviceName: ServiceB
              servicePort: 81
          - path: >-
              /app/api/ServiceB/(.+)
            backend:
              serviceName: ServiceB
              servicePort: 80
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

The c# code `await listener.GetContextAsync()` is never executed.

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("wss://*:81/app/api/ServiceB/subscription/");
var listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
```

The error that I get at client side  : `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

Please suggest if you find something wrong here.

Comment: does it work when you add [websoccet annotation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket#websocket-support)

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry, i didnt notice this comment here.Unfortunately, i had already tried it. but that didn't work. I had the same issue when I setup the system in IIS and i had to run **netsh http add sslcert ipport** to enable the HTTPS communication over the specific port. But I dont see any similar commands to allow the IP rule for certificates in AKS. Any suggestions?